# How to find which apple watch 38 or 42mm?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

What is the correct way to find out which apple watch is it programmatically whether it's 38mm or 42mm? How can I make a struct object for the same to access it like below:

```
if watch.size == 38 { 
} else { 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528792/how-to-tell-if-current-running-apple-watch-size-dimension-is-38mm-or-42mm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check Apple Watch size in below following way:-

```
public struct watch {

     public static var screenWidth: CGFloat {
          return WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.width
     }

     public static var is38: Bool {
          return screenWidth == 136
     }

     public static var is42: Bool {
          return screenWidth == 156
     }
}
```